# why Double.valueof can handle "1D" while Long.valueof cannot handle "1L"?

Tags: java, double, long-integer

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Double.valueOf("1D"));
        System.out.println(Double.valueOf("1.1d"));
        System.out.println(Long.valueOf("1L"));
        System.out.println(Long.valueOf("11l"));
    }
}
```

```
1.0
1.1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1L"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:803)
    at Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

Why Double.valueof can handle "1D" while Long.valueof cannot handle "1L"?

Well is it a smelly bad design about this inconsistency?

Comment: Text parsing isn't as simple as you might expect. `System.out.println(Long.valueOf(1L));` is consistent. Basically, why do you want to treat `"1L"` as a valid integral value? As for `double`, consider `System.out.println(Double.valueOf("1.27e5"));`

Comment: "Why Double.valueof can handle "1D" while Long.valueof cannot handle "1L"?" Because they are designed this way. "is it a smelly bad design about this inconsistency?" That is opinion-based and not suitable for stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

*"Why?"* **Convenience.**

A `Long` value is easy to define, i.e. all digits with optional sign, so they defined it that way.

A `Double` value is complex, so they decided to **re-use** as much as possible from the Java language's definition of a floating point literal *([JLS 3.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2))*, and added just what was necessary, i.e. the sign and the special values (`NaN` and `Infinity`).

Sure, that got the unnecessary suffix too, but so what, it doesn't hurt, it'll just be ignored if present, which it really never is anyway.